# Apache Passthrough Flag not working

Tags: apache, redirect, server

I have 2 apache servers. Server 'A' forwards the request it recieves to Server 'B' if the request is of the form ^/en/login server-b.net/en/login.

When the request is forwarded from A to B, I would like to retain my Server A's url in the browser, i.e., server-a.net/en/login.

I have applied the following rules in httpd.conf of Server 'A' but redirects happen with changes in the URL in browserwhen the GET request is made on 
http://server-a.net/en/login

```
ProxyPass /en/login http://server-b.net/en/login
ProxyPassReverse /en/login http://server-b.net/en/login
```

I did also try the following configs but the result is the same:

```
RewriteRule ^/en/login$ http://server-b.net/en/login [PT]
```

Could you please let me know if I am missing anything?
Thanks!
-V